# not showing excel data in gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

when i press button id is btnshow it is not showing uploaded excel file data in gridview , what could be a problem?

```
protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xls" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) == ".xlsx") 
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/payment.xlsx"));
        Label1.Text = "File Uploded";
    }

    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Upload only Excel File";
    }

}

protected void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currpath = Server.MapPath("~/upload/payment.xlsx");
    string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + currpath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";

    OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    try
    {
        oledbConn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

        OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();
        objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1, "ExcelData");
        GridView1.DataSource = objDataset1;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Label1.Text = "" + ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        oledbConn.Close();
    }
```

`

Comment: no,no error.just gridview remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set datasource to a table, not to the dataset. 
**EDIT :** By default datasource will be set to Tables[0]. So your code should work fine. But in the markup you should have `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` for the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

You can download the project I have used to test your code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0UGV0Q3QwZVdoRXc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: sorry forgot to write in code but already did that and it isn't working either